# Website layout gets messy under different screens resolutions

Tags: html, css, layout, screen

I'm designing a website. My monitor's resolution is **1280 x 1024** and I usually use **Firefox** for developing. This is how it looks and should look. This one is the correct one.

[image]

But there's a slight change when viewed in **Chrome** in the same monitor. Notice the right bottom corner.

[image]

Things get even worse when viewed in a another monitor with a different screen resolution. This is my screen at work which's resolution is **1366 x 768**.

On **Firefox**

[image]

On **Chrome**

[image]

As you can see, the layout is messed up pretty bad. Below is the code.

*HTML*

```
<img id="yellowRing" src="images/about_rings/yellow_ring.png" />
<img id="magentaRing" src="images/about_rings/magenta_ring.png" />
<img id="blueRing" src="images/about_rings/blue_ring.png" />

<div id="aboutCaption">
    <p>Our Team</p>
</div>

<div id="team">
    <div class="member"><a data-member="one" href="#"><img src="images/team/one_thumbnail.png" /></a></div>
    <div class="member"><a data-member="two" href="#"><img src="images/team/two_thumbnail.png" /></a></div>
    <div class="member"><a data-member="three" href="#"><img src="images/team/three_thumbnail.png" /></a></div>
    <div class="member"><a data-member="four" href="#"><img src="images/team/four_thumbnail.png" /></a></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#yellowRing {
    position:absolute;
    left:1200px;
    bottom:-1300px;
    z-index:2;  
}

#magentaRing {
    position:absolute;
    left:1600px;
    bottom:-1100px;
    z-index:3;
}

#blueRing {
    position:absolute;
    left:2160px;
    top:500px;
    z-index:4;
}


#aboutCaption {
    position:absolute;
    left:2430px;
    top:-50px;
    z-index:4;
    line-height:2.2em;
}

#aboutCaption p {
    font-weight:lighter;
    text-align:right;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:55px;
}

#team {
    position:absolute;
    left:2135px;
    top:90px;
    width:432px;
    height:110px;
    z-index:4;
}

.member {
    position:relative;
    height:95px;
    width:95px;
    margin:8px 8px 8px 0px;
    z-index:5;
    display:inline-block;
}

.member:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left:8px;    
}

.member img {
    height:95px;
    width:95px; 
}
```

This website only scrolls horizontally. My question is, why this is happening? And what should I do to make the layout consistent despite the screen size or the resolution? Or do I have to go about the responsive design and include multiple CSS files per benchmark?

Thank you.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  When you have different resolutions, you are physically looking at more (or less) of the available real estate.  Shouldn't you expect that your image(s) will be clipped with a resolution having a shorter vertical height?

Comment: Using an embedded image here instead of background images seems highly inappropriate since they are purely decorative.

Answer (score 0):

To cover all platforms/browsers/etc... you will have to euther use a framework, which gets bulky, or if you're keeping it simple, I would go with some @media rules in order to cover your different layout dimensions.  Basics of it can be found at [W3 Media Types](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)

Comment: Frameworks are not a magic bullet that will solve this problem.

Comment: Didn't state they were.  Was technically advising against and saying to write it out, and if necessary use @media rules to cover platforms and browsers.  You're a little fast on the trigger there...